# pandas string to date type conversion in proper format

Tags: pandas

I am getting date data in string format in pandas like `10-Oct`,`11-Oct` but i want to make it date data type like this format  `2019-10-10,2019-10-11`
is there any easy way available in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with added year and parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['10-Oct', '11-Oct']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + '-2019', format='%d-%b-%Y')
print (df)
        date
0 2019-10-10
1 2019-10-11
```